# Inheritance and derived attribute disappearing in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, hashmap, delete-operator

I'm quite new to the concept of inheritance, and to C++ too, so my problem may be really stupid...

```
class A {
    public :
        A() {}
        A(string name) {name_ = name}

    private :
        string name_;
}

class B : public A {
    public :
        B() {}
        B(string name, int number) {
            name_ = name;
            number_ = number;
        }

    private :
        string name;
        int number;
}

class C {
    public :
        C() {}
        void addClass(int id, A* a) {
            map[id] = a;
        }

    private :
        Hash_Map<int, A*> map;
}

void main() {
    C* c = new C();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        B* b = new B("randomName", 50);
        c->addClass(i, b); //1st problem
        delete b;            //2nd problem
    }

}
```

1st problem : shouldn't "map" in "c" keep the attribute "number" from the class "B"? I know I put A* in parameter, but if I had several class that derived from A, how should I do it?

2nd problem : All of my attributes in "map" seem to get random values when I delete "b". I'm guessing the problem is that I need to copy "b" into a new object, but how can I do it if I have "A*" as my addClass() parameter? My pointer b seems to be converted into its parent class

EDIT : had to change several things in my code that I forgot...

Comment: It does keep `number` but it's private, I recommend making it protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bunch of problems:

1) No initializing members within a class declaration! (Your edit fixed this)

```
class B : public A {
public :
    B() : name("A"), number(0) {} // initialize in constructor. that's what they are for!

private :
    string name;
    int number;
```

}

(Repeat that for A's declaration as well)

2)
You're storing a copy of the pointer to `A` (that was passed in as argument to addClass)in your map, not the actual object.
So, your map holds: 100 -> pointer to `b`

Then you delete whatever b points to. What would you think `map[100]` contains now? 
A pointer to garbage! So, don't delete the pointer outside! Let C take care of it.

3) (My previous answer had a glaring error and someone voted it up. So, I'll keep the earlier part and point out my mistake) 
Don't use pointers unless you need to. Save yourself some work. Go play the guitar or read some of Herb Sutter's articles!

```
void main() {
   // don't use pointers and require that you delete them (unless you need to)
   B b; // default constructor is called automatically. it is destroyed for you, by the compiler
        // at the end of its scope (in this case, closing brace of main() )

   C c; 
   c.addClass(100, b);
}
```

Let's fix C too. Can we get rid of those nasty pointers?

```
class C {
public :
    C() {}
    void addClass(const int id, const A a) { // use const, its a good habit!
        map[id] = a;
    }

private :
    Hash_Map<int id, A a> map;
```

}

Now, what's wrong with this? Not just extra copies; when you pass `b` as argument to addClass by value, the compiler is gonna copy the `A` portion of `b! So, we lost`b`'s data (and overrides)!

So, we absolutely have to use pointers (references are dangerous, since they're deleted at scope exit).

What's important is that you make C owns the deletion.

So your code would now look like:

```
class C {
public :
    C() {}
    ~C() {
       for(pair<int, A*>& p : map) // C++11 syntax, yay!
          delete p.second; // here's where you clean up. not in main.

    }
    void addClass(const int id, const A* a) {
        map[id] = a;
    }

private :
    Hash_Map<int, A*> map;
}

void main() {
    B* b = new B(); // back to square 1!
    C c;
    c.addClass(100, &b);
} // no memory leaks
```

But I hate taking care of deletion you say.. Fear not, we have shared_ptr!

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
typedef shared_ptr<A> Aptr;

class C {
public :
    C() {}
    ~C() {
        cout << "Drinking a beer coz i use shared_ptr";     
    }
    void addClass(const int id, Aptr& a) {
        map[id] = a;
    }

private :
    Hash_Map<int, Aptr> map;
}

void main() {
    Aptr b(new B());
    C c;
    c.addClass(100, b);
} // still no memory leaks
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, my example is quite bad. I had to use pointers in my program, but tried to oversimplify it in this post...

Comment: Use shared_ponters (or smart pointers) so that you don't lose the object. There is no need to call delete once you use shared pointer. If your map<int, shared_pointer<A> > holds shared pointer of A, you would not need to worry about their deletion.

Comment: oh yes, use shared pointers if you can. if not, figure out where to clean up. RAII is a great principle - cleanup in your destructor.